# Anyone know whats up with Heroku1?

Tags: heroku

Been searching for any more info on Heroku1 (https://www.heroku.com/1) but sadly still not a peep.

Supposed to provide auto syncing between Postgres and Salesforce which would be a huge win for our development methods but sadly no word on pricing or availability.

Anyone know anything?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an upcoming feature.

Comment: For the availability, see [Wait List Signup](https://www.heroku.com/1#signup): "Heroku1 is available now in limited availability, and will be generally available in early 2014."

Answer (score 1):

This is not the forum to ask about an upcoming product.

(It is in very limited pre-beta right now, and is still evolving, but I can verify from personal experience that it does do some pretty amazing stuff.)

Comment: Do you know if any current info under NDA?

Comment: Good question. No clue. So discretion is the way to go and I'm keeping my mouth shut.  And to whomever down voted my answer: Just because you don't like an answer, it doesn't mean you should down vote it.